# Python Import Error on installed library - paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I am trying to run a python script that uses the paramiko library. When I run my script I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 26, in <module>
   import paramiko
ImportError: No module named paramiko
```

The module is clearly installed.

```
$ pip list | grep paramiko                                                                           
paramiko                     2.8.0
```

Why does python refuse to acknowledge this? How do I troubleshoot?

Edit

```
pip --version
pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)

which python
/usr/bin/python

python --version                                                                                                                                                          
Python 2.7.18

python script.py
```

I find the pip thing strange. I thought pip3 was used for python3 and pip was used for earlier versions. What is happening here?

Comment: How do you launch your python script ? What is the output of `pip --version` ? What is the output `<your python executable> --version` and `which <your python executable>` ? Are the version of python used by pip and your python executable the same ?

Comment: you may have multiple versions of Python installed (such as if you're using a mac, you may find you're really using or installing with the default python 2.7 installation)

Comment: @Zeitounator - I have added the answers to those questions to the post.

Comment: You installed the lib in python3, you launch your script with python2.7. Either use python3 for your script or install the lib in python2.7. What `pip` points to depends on your distro and the various install commands you have been issuing. `pip2` should do the trick to install in python 2.7 though.